# Are packages siunitx and xfrac incompatible? - "redefsymbols"

Tags: siunitx, incompatibility, xfrac

Is this a bug? Where can this be reported? Can someone of you report this?

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xfrac}

\begin{document}
bla
\end{document}
```

Output:

```
redefsymbols
bla
```

However, with this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
bla
\end{document}
```

Output:

```
bla
```

Thanks! (Also, if you can reproduce this behavior can you please leave a comment?)

Comment: I don't get anything strange in both cases. Maybe you have outdated versions of the packages. What TeX distribution are you using?

Comment: Both work fine for me; add `\listfiles` immediately before your `begin{document}` and check that [your system is up to date](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution). In general, package ordering *can* matter (especially with `hyperref` for example)